# JAVA - Compression/Decompression using LZ4 library

Tags: java, lz4

I need to compress/decompress values contained in a hash table.
Since LZ4 seems to provide better performance than GZip, I'm trying it.

Here my code.
In particular, `table_data_cache` is a `HashMap<String, List<Object>>` where each list has 2 object and only the first one has to be compressed

**COMPRESSION**

```
table_data_cache.forEach((kk,vv) -> {

            try{
                ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
                o.writeObject(vv.get(0));
                byte[] source = b.toByteArray();
                int decompressedLength = source.length;
                LZ4Factory factory = LZ4Factory.fastestInstance();
                LZ4Compressor compressor = factory.fastCompressor();
                int maxCompressedLength = compressor.maxCompressedLength(decompressedLength);
                byte[] compressed = new byte[maxCompressedLength];
                int compressLen = compressor.compress(source, 0, decompressedLength, compressed, 0, maxCompressedLength);
                 byte[] finalCompressedArray = Arrays.copyOf(compressed, compressLen);
                List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(finalCompressedArray);
                list.add(vv.get(1));
                table_data_cache_compressed.put(kk, list);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**DECOMPRESSION**

```
table_data_cache_compressed.forEach((kkk,vvv)->{
            List<AbstractClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
            try{

                LZ4Factory factory = LZ4Factory.fastestInstance();
                LZ4FastDecompressor decompressor = factory.fastDecompressor();

                byte[] src = (byte[])vvv.get(0);
                byte[] restored = "".getBytes();
                decompressor.decompress(src, restored);
                ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(restored));
                list = (List<AbstractClass>) objectIn.readObject();
                CacheStatus status = (CacheStatus) vvv.get(1);
                System.out.println("key: "+kkk+" ID1: "+list.get(0).getParameterValue("REG_MAP_ID", "int", section_name)+" timestamp: "+status.getTIMESTAMP());

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                CacheStatus status = (CacheStatus) vvv.get(1);
            System.out.println("key: "+kkk+" ID1: "+list.get(0).getParameterValue("REG_MAP_ID", "int", section_name)+" timestamp: "+status.getTIMESTAMP());
        });
```

But I have the following error:

**net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4Exception: Error decoding offset 1 of input buffer**

What is wrong?

Comment: I tried to adjust the `restored` size by setting it to `3*src.lenght`, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Fab- Have you ever solve this issue? I have one query like If I don't know the length of decompressed array then how should I decompressed byte array? I have one compressed byte array. I want to decompress it.